# Swagger/Swashbuckle annotations in a class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am using Swagger data annotations (`x.EnableAnnotations();`) and everything is working as intended in the `AspNetCore` app's controllers. I am able to use annotations like `SwaggerOperation` and `SwaggerResponse` to document my controllers.

Now I want to annotate my classes.
Something like

```
public class Record : Base
{    
    [SwaggerSchema(WriteOnly = true)]
    public string AppId { get; set; }
}
```

My classes are in a different project from the `AspNetCore` app. They are DTOs and they are in their own class library. The issue is when I try install `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations` in the class library I get an error in my Blazor client app that references my DTO class library.

I think the actual issue is that `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations` cannot be referenced into a class library project, so doesn't work there, yet pops up on the Blazor app side.

That said I can't imagine I am the only one who has DTOs outside their main `AspNetCore` app.

What am I missing? Is there some other way to annotate classes in Swagger that should be used in a situation like this?

Comment: Not sure if this is related to your problem. If it is I can change to an answer. Could you take a look at this: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/2362?msclkid=cb458d31a64811ec8beb37db8450f0e9#issuecomment-1069184316

Comment: It is I am pretty sure but that's not really my question. My question is more of what to do about it. Some elaboration and/or examples on `Moving the annotation extension and filter types to a separate project can solve the issue` would help a lot.

Comment: Are you referencing this library from a Web API project *and* a Blazor project? Swashbuckle is not meant for Blazor/wasm, so the answer may simply be that you have to split your models into two libraries. One that has the annotations (for the Web API) and one that doesn't have the annotations (for the Blazor project). If that's the case, I can suggest a solution that allows the split yet reuse the models (maybe).

Comment: Yep pretty much. I have two class libraries one with DB models and one with Domain (DTO) models. `NetCore` app references both and converts them as needed with using `AutoMapper`. `Blazor` references Domain only.

Answer (score 0):

Based on our conversation in the comments, it seems you need to try one or more of the following

- ensure models only used by the Blazor app are defined in class library 1, and referenced only by the Blazor project. These models can't have annotations because of the restriction that Blazor/wasm can't use Swagger's annotations library.
- ensure models only used by the web API are defined in class library 2, and referenced by the web API project. These can have annotations.
- for models without annotations used by by both, you can put those in class library 3 and reference that from library 1 and 2

The final case is models used by both *that also have annotations*. This is going to require special treatment. You can either

- duplicate the models into class library 1 and 2, but in 2 add the annotations. This obviously destroys reuse.

or

- define an interface for the shared models in class library 1. Implement the interface in class library 1 without annotations. Implement the interface in class library 2 (which will now have to reference 1), but add the annotations only to the implementation in class library 2.

The latter is still not ideal because there's some non-reuse. I think you'll just have to accept that.

You end up with a structure like

1. Blazor App --> library 1 (has non-annotated shared models, non-shared/non-annotated models, interfaces for shared/annotated models) --> library 3
2. Web API --> library 2 --> library 3 where library 2 has non-annotated models and implementations with annotations of shared interfaces)

Comment: That's what I have been thinking too.  Are there no other methods to describe classes in swagger?

Comment: Yes, there are other methods. You might want to look at [filters](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore?msclkid=308e092eac4c11ecb972854ad1d70dee#extend-generator-with-operation-schema--document-filters).